# Prevent anchor link overflow from being clickable

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an anchor element with a child element(img) that is bigger than the anchor element. I would like to set the anchor links 'clickable' area to only the anchor element.

```
<div>
  <a href="">
    <img src="somewhere/images/this.svg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPaJrR) demonstrating the clickable area outside of the anchor element.

I would like to not have to break these into sibling elements if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indirectly possible.

The problem is that the anchor element is the parent element, which means that clicking on any of its children element is subsequently a click on the anchor. To work around this, you can [disable click events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the child `svg` element. In doing so, only the anchor element is clickable.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGPERy)

```
a.yellow-clickable > svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

In any *other* circumstance, the solution would be pretty straightforward. Just add `overflow: hidden` to the anchor element.

Comment: that css almost did the trick! 
The area where the parent was before position:absolute is still clickable.
I have to read up on pointer-events.

Comment: Gotcha, both have to be absolute... thanks for the help!